# Highlighting many ranges on an axis of a Bokeh plot?

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a scatter plot of data and would like to highlight certain ranges of the x-axis. When the number ranges to highlight are relatively small, using [`BoxAnnotation`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#box-annotations) works well. However, I'm trying to make many adjacent highlightings (with different opacity). With many adjacent `BoxAnnotations`, zoomed out, the boxes slightly overlap, creating lines. Additionally, thousands of `BoxAnnotations` takes a long time to generate and does not run smoothly when interacting with the plot.

To be more specific about my case, I have some temporal data and a predictive model detecting the probability of some event occurring in the data. I want each segment to be highlighted with an opacity given by the probability that an event is occurring at that point in time. However, my current `BoxAnnotation` approach results in artificial lines from overlap of boxes when zoomed out (they disappear when zooming in on a region), and slow responsiveness of the interactive plot.

Is there a way to accomplish something similar to this without the artifacts and with a smoother experience?

**Current method:**

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=data_frame)
figure_ = figure(x_axis_label='Time', y_axis_label='Intensity')
for index in range(data_frame.shape[0] - 1):
    figure_.add_layout(
        BoxAnnotation(left=data_frame['time'].values[index], right=data_frame['time'].values[index + 1],
                      fill_alpha=data_frame['prediction'].values[index], fill_color='red', line_alpha=0)
    )
figure_.circle(x='time', y='intensity', source=source)
show(figure_)
```

**Example of artificial lines when there are too many small adjacent `BoxAnnotations`:**
[image]

**When zooming on the x-axis, the lines disappear:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's probably not any way to salvage this exact approach. The artifacts are due to the functioning of the underlying raster HTML canvas, and here's not anything that can be one about that. And any slowness is due to the fact that this kind of use of `BoxAnnotation` (with so very many individual instances) is not at all what was envisioned, and it is simply not optimized to show hundreds of instances the way e.g. scatter glyphs are. You are trying to use box annotations to construct a sort of translucent heat map, and that is not a good fit for it, for the reasons above.

You could potentially overcome slowness by using a single `rect` or `vbar` glyph that draws all the boxes at once in a vectorized way. But that won't alleviate the compositing issues.

Your best bet is to create a semi-transparent "heatmap" image overlay yourself with a tool or code that can afford better control over the details of rasterization and compositing. I can't really advise you on how to do that in any detail. The [Datashader](http://datashader.org/) library might be useful for this.